# Timer accuracy when using getTimer()-starttime after buttonpress

Tags: actionscript-3

I am planning on conducting a scientific experiment in which timekeeping precision will be very important. The application that I will be using is developed in Adobe AIR and it should measure the time between two on-screen button presses. Now I have read some things about the accuracy of the Timer in AS3 and that it is subpar because it depends on performance and frame count, I believe, but I am wondering whether in my situation this will be a problem since I only need to measure the time difference after the second button click, an event that is initiated after the press.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I expect if your app will be as lightweight as possible, you can achieve accuracy of 1ms with `getTimer()` due to practical elimination of frame rendering time when events are not processed. But there are more OS-dependant discrepancies that are out of AIR developer's control that will likely mitigate your attempt of getting more precision than once per frame (16ms tops). Of course, the app should be activated all the time.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 

The App will always be activated and on the forefront, and indeed its not really heavy (just the two static buttons visible). The starttime is registred after a mousemove event (in order to leave out response time after a click), then it just waits for the second click and it uses getTimer() again to calculate the result.

Also, does it matter what I use ase the stage frame rate? Right now I use 30 fps.

Comment: If you don't receive outputs that are not divisible by 33 (1000/30) then it should matter, this means that precision of less than frame time is not achieveable. If you don't need to capture times that are less than one frame, it should not matter. I think tests should provide actual constraints, unfortunately I am not able to develop for mobile yet.

Comment: Actually my application is not for mobile, it is just an Air application on the desktop. Just out of curiosity, why is it that I need to get output that is devisible by 33?

Comment: Say your app runs at 30 frames per second, then each frame is displayed each 33 ms. So, if you receive your mouse click event only once per frame, the delays will be more than 33 ms, and most likely divisible by 33.